# Identifying button press events in Java Scrips

Tags: javascript

How can I perform certain set of actions, when the user presses ctrl + F11 on my Javascript page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you must have jQuery library.

```
 $(document).on("keydown", function(e){
      if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 122){
        //your action
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using plain javascript as well. You need to use both the keyDown and keyPress event to find out when the keys are getting presses and released.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ctrlKey and functionKey example</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ctrl = 0;

function captureCtrl(e){
if (e.ctrlKey == true)
    ctrl = 1;

}

function actualFunction(e) {
alert (ctrl + " : " + e.keyCode);

if (e.ctrlKey == true)
    ctrl = 0;

}

</script>
</head>

<body onkeydown="captureCtrl(event);"  onkeypress="actualFunction(event);">

<p> Press and hold your ctrl + funct key. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically you can set a variable to capture control key press and combine that with keypress go get your desired result. Cheers!